# How to update a specific field data in multiple rows in a table in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Here i have a number of data in a table, but i want to update on only one single fields data in that table.

And i want to change these product_image field values with "https"

**For example:**

this is my current value: http://weshareresources.s3.amazonaws.com/14619475790.jpg

and i want to change with: https://weshareresources.s3.amazonaws.com/14619475790.jpg

**database name**: renters_test

**table name**: fc_rental_photos

**name of field which i want to update**: product_image

**Here is my table screenshot:**

[image]

Please suggest me that one sql query, where i can replace these "http" with "https" with their following path. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE fc_rental_photos set product_image = REPLACE(product_image, 'http', 'https');
```

The **REPLACE** does that trick.

Run that SQL Code in PhpMyAdmin and it updates all your **http** to **https**

Reference : [REPLACE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql)

Comment: but i want to keep their existing path with changed value.

like:

current value: "http://blabla"
and requested value:  "https:/blabla"

Comment: That SQL Code would only change the http to https. It wont remove the existing path.

Comment: there are a few values wchich does not have any "http", are those values affected or not?

Comment: Nope. They won't be affected. All that sql query gonna do is that 
It searches the product_image values for any "http" 
Then changes it to "https"
If it doesn't find "http" in it. It won't change anything.

Comment: Ok then, Thanks :)

Comment: If you don't mind, then please upvote my question. i'm new on this community and want to learn more, Thanks :)

Answer (score -2):

you need to manually fetch the record of that column i.e. "product_image" and use "str_replace" function  for eg. in your case , it will become ,

```
echo str_replace("http","https","Your column value");
```